# How to rotate an image on key press in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making a lunar lander game, and want the spaceship to rotate when the left and right arrow keys are pressed.

I know how to move an image using a picture box and the keydown event, but there isn't anyway to directly *rotate* a picture box. Do i need to use the image a different way to be able to achieve what I want? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: Rotate the image instead of the picturebox.  Easily done with Graphics.RotateTransform + DrawImage.  Might as well lose the picture box since it is completely unhelpful.

Comment: actually dont "Might" lose the picture box, You have to lose it because if you will rotate the image inside the picture box it will cut of  parts of the image (in a square shape), You can make the image bigger and then when it is rotated it will cut of the edges of the image but not the "Space ship" part. With this been said Don't use a picture box rendering a picture box takes a lot of time and it may flicker due to the redraw events (when the picture box moved)

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class inheriting from picturebox. Use that. You can edit the designer.vb to change the type.

This is pseudocode, untested, so it certainly won't run.

```
class RotateablePictureBox
    inherits picturebox

    public property RotationAngle as single

    overrides onpaint(e as ...)
        e.graphics.rotatetransform(rotationangle)
        mybase.onpaint(e)
```

That's the idea that Hans Passant is talking about (might have to do the DrawImage yourself too and skip the mybase.onpaint - it's done like e.graphics.onpaint(TheImage,dimensions etc...))

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time posting code so let me know how I can improve it for the group.  I developed this class using code from http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/391.html`enter code here`

I hope this helps.  This is the button code

```
  Private Sub btnRotateLeft_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRotateLeft.Click
    ' IMAGE IS THE NEW OBJECT FROM THE CLASS. PASS THE PICTUREBOX CONTROL(pbItems)
    image.RotateLeft(pbItems)
  End Sub
```

This is the class

```
Imports System.Math
Public Class clsImage
  Private wid As Single
  Private hgt As Single
  Public Function RotateLeft(ByVal picSource As PictureBox) As PictureBox
    'ROTATES THE IMAGE LEFT
    Dim bm_in = New Bitmap(picSource.Image)
    wid = bm_in.Width
    hgt = bm_in.Height
    Dim corners As Point() = {New Point(0, 0), New Point(wid, 0), New Point(0, hgt), New Point(wid, hgt)}
    Dim cx As Single = wid / 2
    Dim cy As Single = hgt / 2

    Dim i As Long
    'ROTATES LEFT
    For i = 0 To 3
      corners(i).X -= cx
      corners(i).Y -= cy
    Next i
    'THE ROTATION ANGLE IS HARD CODED HERE BUT COULD BE PASS TO THE CLASS
    Dim theta As Single = Single.Parse(90) * PI / 180.0
    Dim sin_theta As Single = Sin(theta)
    Dim cos_theta As Single = Cos(theta)
    Dim X As Single
    Dim Y As Single

    For i = 0 To 3
      X = corners(i).X
      Y = corners(i).Y
      corners(i).X = X * cos_theta + Y * sin_theta
      corners(i).Y = -X * sin_theta + Y * cos_theta
    Next i

    Dim xmin As Single = corners(0).X
    Dim ymin As Single = corners(0).Y

    For i = 1 To 3
      If xmin > corners(i).X Then xmin = corners(i).X
      If ymin > corners(i).Y Then ymin = corners(i).Y
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 3
      corners(i).X -= xmin
      corners(i).Y -= ymin
    Next i

    Dim bm_out As New Bitmap(CInt(-2 * xmin), CInt(-2 * ymin))
    Dim gr_out As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm_out)

    ReDim Preserve corners(2)

    gr_out.DrawImage(bm_in, corners)
    picSource.Image = bm_out
    Return picSource
  End Function
  Public Function RotateRight(ByVal picSource As PictureBox) As PictureBox
    'ROTATES THE IMAGE RIGHT
    Dim bm_in = New Bitmap(picSource.Image)
    wid = bm_in.Width
    hgt = bm_in.Height
    Dim corners As Point() = {New Point(0, 0), New Point(wid, 0), New Point(0, hgt), New Point(wid, hgt)}
    Dim cx As Single = wid / 2
    Dim cy As Single = hgt / 2

    Dim i As Long
    'ROTATES RIGHT
    For i = 0 To 3
      corners(i).X -= cx
      corners(i).Y -= cy
    Next i
    'THE ROTATION ANGLE IS HARD CODED HERE BUT COULD BE PASS TO THE CLASS
    Dim theta As Single = Single.Parse(-90) * PI / 180.0
    Dim sin_theta As Single = Sin(theta)
    Dim cos_theta As Single = Cos(theta)
    Dim X As Single
    Dim Y As Single

    For i = 0 To 3
      X = corners(i).X
      Y = corners(i).Y
      corners(i).X = X * cos_theta + Y * sin_theta
      corners(i).Y = -X * sin_theta + Y * cos_theta
    Next i

    Dim xmin As Single = corners(0).X
    Dim ymin As Single = corners(0).Y

    For i = 1 To 3
      If xmin > corners(i).X Then xmin = corners(i).X
      If ymin > corners(i).Y Then ymin = corners(i).Y
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 3
      corners(i).X -= xmin
      corners(i).Y -= ymin
    Next i

    Dim bm_out As New Bitmap(CInt(-2 * xmin), CInt(-2 * ymin))
    Dim gr_out As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm_out)

    ReDim Preserve corners(2)

    gr_out.DrawImage(bm_in, corners)
    picSource.Image = bm_out
    Return picSource
  End Function
End Class
```